# Range updation of values in c++ vectors

Tags: c++, stdvector

Given a vector of integers v, whose size is n and stores all 0's initially. If I want to update some elements of a range, say from index l to r, where (0<=l<r<n). Is there any efficient way instead of running loop from l to r?

For example,
v = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}.
I want to update elements from l=2 to r=5.

Update refers to v[i] += k, where k is some known value. If k=1, then final updated vector in above case would be-

v = {0,0,1,1,1,1,0}.

Thanks:)

Comment: what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre]

Comment: The bare minimum to implement this is a basic `for` loop. It can't get any more "efficient way" than this. `std::for_each` will write this loop for you, but it'll still be the same `for` loop, in the end.

Comment: [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill), though thats also just a loop. You can try to hide the loop behind a function call, but eventually to do something for n element you still need a loop

Comment: I found one suggestion useful in my case, and so I am sharing it here. 
  
maintain one array b initially storing all 0's. Then for each query (l,r) increase the value at index l by 1 and decrease the value of element at (r+1)th position by 1.  
    After attending all the queries, the required array(stored as d) can be generated as : 
   
d[1] = b[1];
for(j = 2:n) d[j] = d[j-1] + b[j]; 

Thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`for_each` (ccpreference.com)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) or [`for_each_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n)

```
std::vector<int> data{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
std::for_each(data.begin() + 2, data.begin() + 6, [](int& i) { i += 1;});

// or with for_each_n
// std::for_each_n(data.begin() + 2, 4, [](int& i) { i += 1;});

for (const auto i : data) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

But as the comment above mentioned there will be a for loop in there, even though you don't explicitly write one.

Here a short explanation what the code does:

From the reference page we learn:

> Applies the given function object f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in the range [first, last), in order.

In our case we provide for first `data.begin() + 2` which is the 3rd element of the vector and for last we provide `data.begin() + 6`. This element is not included in the application of the function (this is what `[first, last)` means).

The last part is the function `f` that we have to provide. Here we use a lambda function that simply increases the parameter by 1. It's important that the function paramter of the lambda takes a reference (`int& i`) and not just a copy, otherwise the vector remain the same as we only change copies of the elements.